# How to find cuda version in ubuntu?

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-16.04

I installed cuda 8.0 in my ubuntu 16.04 machine and checked the cuda version using the command "nvcc --version". it shows version as 7.5!!!.How Can I be sure that it is accurate? Are there other commands that I can also use to verify my result?

Comment: What's your GPU ? Did you have `cuda` previously installed?

Comment: I have GTX970 GPU. No I didn't installed cuda previously in my system.

Comment: How did you install `cuda` ?

Comment: I downloaded the package from "https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/prod/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64-deb" and I followed the installation instructions.

Comment: Instead of the package, please provide a link to the **instructions** you followed.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the following link http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda7.5-ubuntu but instead of 7.5, I replaced with 8.0.

Comment: What path did you install CUDA 8.0 to? What is the output of `which nvcc`?

Comment: If you are looking for the actual version digits as a string you can use a mix of `nvidia-smi` to get the version, `grep` to identify the line, and `sed` to remove the unnecessary characters:
`nvidia-smi | grep -o 'CUDA Version: [0-9].\.[0-9]' | sed 's/.*: //'`

Answer (score 49):

[edited 2022]

For CUDA 11:

```
$ cat /usr/local/cuda/version.json
```

For cuda-8.0 on Ubuntu16.04, you should be able to read

```
$ cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt
CUDA Version 8.0.44
```

I agree with [Robert Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695960/robert-crovella), you might need to check your PATH

Comment: /usr/local/cuda is a symlink to the version you have installed. You can install cuda without the symlink and then this will not work.

Comment: For me it was :
 cat /usr/local/cuda/version.json

Answer (score 10):

Starting from CUDA 8.0, it's possible to have multiple CUDA versions installed. You can then activate different values for `$PATH` environment variable that will present you with different CUDA version.

Command to immediately obtain the CUDA version:

```
$ nvcc --version | grep "release" | awk '{print $6}' | cut -c2-
```

You can confirm the result by checking the install status of CUDA libraries:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep cuda
```

For installing multiple versions of CUDA, you can refer to [this article](https://tech.amikelive.com/node-859/installing-cuda-toolkit-9-2-on-ubuntu-16-04-fresh-install-install-by-removing-older-version-install-and-retain-old-version/).

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all...
Previously I tried to install cuda8.0 using run file from https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/prod/local_installers/cuda_8.0.44_linux-run. After that I tried to check "nvcc --version", but it shows the following error "The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit". So I tried the above command. It gave the cuda7.5 version.

**Later I tried to install cuda using debian package which by default contained nvcc. Now I am getting correct version.**

Comment: Follow the directions in the linux getting started guide.  When you use a runfile installer, you must update your `PATH` environment variable.  If you don't do that, you will get the message about `nvcc` not being installed.

Answer (score 3):

It may be due to the fact that you have both v7.5 and v8.0 installed. So instead of changing path, try uninstalling v7.5 first